# Applescript: asking the Finder from ApplescriptObjC?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

This one-line Applescript works fine on my Mac:

```
tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Development/Applescript/Rapport.docx"
```

However it fails from a trivial ApplescriptObjC project:

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
        tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Development/Applescript/Rapport.docx"
end applicationWillFinishLaunching:
```

The error I get is:

```
*** -[CMDAppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:]: POSIX file "/Development/Applescript/Rapport.docx" of «script» doesn’t understand the “open” message. (error -1708)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that Finder will open the file using whatever app is set to open that file by default (in Finder, see File>Get Info>Open With). If you want to open the file specifically in Word for further manipulation, use `tell application "Microsoft Word" to open [whatever]`. (Or, if you _only_ want to open a file from ObjC, you don't need AS at all; see [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsworkspace_class) or [LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/LaunchServicesReference).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the problem once and i can't explain this weird behavior but a little rearrangement worked for me:

```
tell application "Finder" to open "/Development/Applescript/Rapport.docx" as POSIX file
```

Comment: To put this in general terms, as of OS X 10.9.2: **in the context of `"Finder`", always use the form `... as POSIX file` rather than `POSIX file ...`**. Why? Only Apple knows.

Comment: It's not a Finder problem. AppleScriptObjC relies on some evil voodoo to insert itself into the AppleScript runtime that prevents AppleScript from interpreting `alias "..."` and `POSIX file "..."` specifiers correctly. What the AppleScript engineers giveth, the AppleScript engineers take away.